# How to replace first part of a string with a given pattern in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string example:

```
\\servername\Client\Range\Product\
```

The `servername`, `Client`, `Range`, and `Product` vales can be anything but they simply represe t a samba share on a server.

I want to be able to take one of these paths and relace everything upto the fourth `\` with a new path: for example:

```
\\10.0.1.1\ITClient\001\0012\ will become:

\\10.0.1.1\Archive\001\0012\
```

All the paths that I get will follow the same start pattern `\\servername\Client\`, using C# how can I replace everything in the string upto the 4th "\"?

I have looked at using regex but I have never been able to understand its wonders and powers

Comment: What did you try? Show us your code.

Comment: It looks like it would be simple to split it up with String.Split, replace the elements you want to, and reconstruct it with String.Join.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: I think this would be best in this case.

Comment: I can do it using string split and a a loop or index replacements but I assume this will be slow

Comment: @AndyClark You should not assume such things. If you think about how a regex runs (e.g. http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html), which do you think will be faster now? What happens when you measure them? Which way is obvious and will be easy to maintain in future?

Comment: hey, just trying to help you out, no need to downvote.

Comment: I havent down voted anything, I cant believe this question has been down voted so many times when it is genuine?

Comment: It looks like you downvoted my answer

Comment: Nope, as a general rule I don't down vote peoples answers to questions unless they are incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Regex pattern will match everything through the 4th `\`

```
^(?:.*?\\){4}
```

usage:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"^(?:.*?\\){4}", @"\\10.0.1.1\Archive\");
```

To elucidate the Regex a bit:

```
^ // denotes start of line
 (?:…) // we need to group some stuff, so we use parens, and ?: denotes that we do not want to use the parens for capturing (this is a performance optimization)
 .*? // denotes any character, zero or more times, until what follows (\)
 \\ //denotes a backslash (the backslash is also escape char)
 {4} // repeat 4 times
```

Comment: Fancy stuff ;) but it would match other patterns to, presumably not a problem in this instance however.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something major, you could just use a mask and format it:

```
static string pathMask = @"\\{0}\{1}\{2}\{3}\";

string server = "10.0.1.1";
string client = "archive";
string range = "001";
string product = "0012";

...

string path = string.Format(pathMask, server, client, range, product);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Format` or `Path.Combine`

```
string template = @"\\{0}\{1}\{2}\{3}\";
string server = "10.0.1.1";
string folder = "Archive";
string range = "001";
string product = "0012";

string s1 = String.Format(template,
    server,
    folder,
    range,
    product);

// s1 = \\10.0.1.1\Archive\001\0012\

string s2 = Path.Combine(@"\\", server, folder, range, product);

// s2 = \\10.0.1.1\Archive\001\0012\
```

Answer (score 1):

Elegant regex solution would be:

```
(new Regex(@"(?<=[^\\]\\)[^\\]+")).Replace(str, "Archive", 1);
```

which replace part of string behind a single slash with *"Archive"* string.

#### Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/F29TM).

Answer (score 0):

The string methods would work but maybe more verbose than a regex. If you want to match everything from the start of the string up to the 4th \ then the following regex will do it (assuming your string meets the pattern provided)

```
^\\\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+\\
```

So some code something like

```
string updated = Regex.Replace(@"\\10.0.1.1\ITClient\001\0012\", "^\\\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+\\", @"\\10.0.1.1\Archive\");
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This one is easy and fast, as long as we are talking about only 4 parts:

```
string example = @"\\10.0.1.1\ITClient\001\0012\";
string[] parts = example.Split(new string[] { @"\" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```